# Cassandra DB connection on Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, cassandra

**EDIT:**

I've tried using Laravel 5.2 and it's not throwing an error anymore. However my problem doesn't stop there as I can't encode the query result to json. I can't identify if cassandra is returning an array or whatever but I'm sure it ain't json.

---

Original Post:

I've tried [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/1/php-driver-datastax-cassandra-db-how-to-use/replies/291448) suggestion over at laracasts but it still won't let my laravel connect to cassandra.

What I'm doing is put the sample code from https://github.com/datastax/php-driver#quick-start, put it on my controller, and modify the cql statement. The raw php works but when I put it on my controller it throws an error.

The error I'm facing is:

> Undefined property: Cassandra\Cluster\Builder::$build

Code that I used:

```
<?php
$cluster   = Cassandra::cluster()->withContactPoints('172.17.0.2')->build();
$keyspace  = 'testspace';
$session   = $cluster->connect($keyspace);
$statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement(
    'SELECT * FROM users'
);
$future    = $session->executeAsync($statement);
$result    = $future->get();

echo "Connected to <b>" . $keyspace . "</b> keyspace <br><br>";

foreach ($result as $row) {
    printf("The id number <b>%s</b> belongs to <b>%s %s</b>. <br>", $row['user_$
}
```

I'm guessing laravel is still trying to know where should it look for those functions even though they're php extensions.

Laravel version: 5.3
Cassandra version: 3.9